# Mesosphere installation PermissionError:/genconf/config.yaml

Tags: mesosphere

I got a Mesosphere-EE, and install on fedora 23 server (kernel 4.4)with:

$bash dcos_generate_config.ee.sh --web –v

then output:

```
Running mesosphere/dcos-genconf docker with BUILD_DIR set to/home/mesos-ee/genconf
Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt
dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
07:53:46:: Logger set to DEBUG
07:53:46:: ====> Starting DCOS installer in web mode
07:53:46:: DCOS Installer v1
07:53:46:: Starting server ('0.0.0.0', 9000)
```

Then I start firefox though vnc, the vnc is on root. then:

```
07:53:57:: Root page requested. 07:53:57:: Serving/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dcos_installer/templates/index.html
07:53:58:: Request for configuration type made. 
07:53:58::Configuration file not found, /genconf/config.yaml. Writing new onewith all defaults. 
07:53:58:: Error handling request
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/genconf/config.yaml'
```

But I already have a genconf/config.yaml, it look like:

```
bootstrap_url: http://<bootstrap_public_ip>:<your_port>
cluster_name: '<cluster-name>'
exhibitor_storage_backend: zookeeper
exhibitor_zk_hosts: <host1>:2181,<host2>:2181,<host3>:2181
exhibitor_zk_path: /dcos
master_discovery: static
master_list:
- <master-private-ip-1>
- <master-private-ip-2>
- <master-private-ip-3>
superuser_username: <username>
superuser_password_hash: <hashed-password>
resolvers:
- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4
```

I do not know what’s going on. If you have any idear, please let me know, thank you very much!

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have exactly the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Disable Selinux!

Configure `SELINUX=disabled` in the `/etc/selinux/config` file and then reboot!
Be ensure the selinux is disabled by the command `getenforce`.

```
$ getenforce 
Disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

zhe.
Correctly installing the enterprise edition depends on the correct system prerequisites. Anyway I suppose you're still on the bootstrap node so I will give you some path to succed in your current task.
Run the script as root or as a user issuing sudo dcos_generate_config.ee.sh
The script will also generate the config file automatically; if you want to use your own configuration file then create a folder named genconf and put it inside before running the script. You should changes the values inside <> with your specific configuration. If you need more help for your specific case send me an email to infofs2 at gmail.com

Comment: I have solved the trouble. The SELINUX should be DISABLED, also, DC/OS is supported only by RHEL, CoreOS and CentOS, not Fedora. Thank you all the same.

Comment: I installed both the early and stable mesosphere suites on fedora without any trouble. Regarding selinux I added the related policies by setsebool without disabling it. On CoreOS things are a little bit different since the rules have to be included in the polkitd configuration. They also support ubuntu/debian (the container of the bootstrap is based on those ones). As you can see the sh script contains the compressed docker image I mentioned. For that reason its weight is of 700MB but the main bash code ia made of just a few lines so really try to avoid disabling selinux.

Comment: You are really cool! But now, I got some trouble about installing dcos-ee on RHEL 7.1. I will send you an email.